# how to extract description from HTML paragraph using Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

I want to extract HTML paragraph from the HTML source. But it's getting data of color and id along with it.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

description = soup.find(
    'div', {'class': 'description-preview body-2 css-1pbvugb'}).text
print(description)
```

Comment: BTW, for your further questions. `<p>` is called HTML paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Just use .find p with after it.

```
description = soup.find('div', {'class':'description-preview body-2 css-1pbvugb'}).find("p").text
```

Comment: there's no need to mention the full `class` name and even you don't need to search for a property ! you can just access it as a method. `soup.select_one('.description-preview').p.string`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the text of the next `<p>`:

```
description = soup.find('div', {'class':'description-preview body-2 css-1pbvugb'}).find_next('p').text
```

Comment: there's no need to mention the full `class` name and even you don't need to search for a property ! you can just access it as a method. `soup.select_one('.description-preview').p.string`

Comment: Yes.  I left it in so it was the smallest diff from the op's original code.

Answer (score 1):

if that's your only target from the link, so you don't need to use a real parser in that case, since that's will loads all the content within `cache` memory.

You can compare the operation time using `regex` or `bs4` parser.

below is a quick catch:

```
import re
import requests

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003')

match = re.search(r'descriptionPreview\":\"(.+?)\"', r.text).group(1)
print(match)
```

Output:

```
Designed with every woman in mind, the mixed material upper of the Nike Air Max Viva 
features a plush collar, detailed patterning and intricate stitching. The new lacing 
system uses 2 separate laces constructed from heavy-duty tech chord, letting you find the perfect fit. Mixing comfort with style, it combines Nike Air with a lifted foam 
heel for and unbelievable ride that looks as good as it feels.
```

In case if you would like to use `bs4`:

Here's a short usage:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.description-preview').p.string)
```

> Note: i used `lxml` parser as it's the quickest parser according to [bs4-documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)